# How to call a function without the required arguments?

Tags: python, function, instantiation

I would like to create a list of functions that set the default values of previously defined functions so later on I can call them with only one argument. The problem is that the first argument is required so I get an error. What is the most pythonic way to go about it?

```py
def plus(num, a1):
    return num + a1

def div(num, a1):
    return num / a1;

acts = [plus(a1 = 3), div(a1 = 3), div(a1 = 2)]

num = 9
for act in acts:
    num = act(num)
```

my desired behavior is for num to be 9 -> 12 -> 4 -> 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `funtools.partial`, you need to flip the parameters since partial applies them in order:

```
from functools import partial

def plus(a1, num):
    return num + a1

f = partial(plus, 3)
```

As example:

```
>>> f = partial(plus, 3)
>>> f(10)
13
```

Or use defaults:

```
def div(num, a1=1):
    return num / a1

fdiv = partial(div, a1=3)
```

For example:

```
>>> acts = [partial(plus, 3), partial(div,a1 = 3), partial(div, a1 = 2)]
>>> num = 9
>>> for act in acts:
...     num = act(num)
...
>>> num
2.0
```

Comment: Partial also allows for keywords. No need to swap parameters.

Comment: `partial` accepts keywords arguments: `partial(plus, a1=3)` will work with the original definition of `plus`.

Comment: thank you guys, you are so quick, I was actually expanding the answer :)

Comment: Just what I was looking for ^-^ this has the added benefit of allowing functions multiple partial arguments. tyty

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you can do something like:

```
def plus(num, a1):
    return num + a1

def div(num, a1):
    return num / a1;

acts = [(plus, 3), (div, 3), (div, 2)]

num = 9
for func, arg in acts:
    print(func(num, arg))
```

which allows you to pre-enter arguments to a list and iterate over.